# Best way to compare Time (or Date) in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqldatatypes

I need two comparisons in my Sql server, One between Dates and One between Times. I'm using C# and Sql Server and Linq-to-sql. I want to store two time fields (Enter-Time, Exit-Time). Now I want to get the difference (e.g. 12:30 , 18:15 the difference is 5:45). What Data Type should I use? I have the same issue with Dates, I want to get the difference of two Dates but "DateTime" Data Type stores redundant data about time, I just need date. I want the easiest way with the least code possible. I'm currently saving like this "1045" when I fetch it I add a ":" to the middle and it becomes "10:45" and there are lot's of problems this way.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. If it is just about SQL, why the references to C# and LINQ? Also, what version of SQL Server? 2008+ has data types specific to this issue.

Comment: sorry man that was a mistake, I removed those tags, thanks

Comment: What version of SQL Server? SQL Server 2008 introduced separate [DATE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630352.aspx) and [TIME](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677243.aspx) data types.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I have Persian Dates, for example we have 6 months with 31 days and 5 months with 30 days and no month with 28 days (but in English Dates you have 28 day months). Is there a problem if I save my dates like 1391/06/31?

Comment: For Persian dates you're going to have trouble natively. Some folks have made functions to help though, see [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28129/Creating-a-CLR-Persian-Date-Convertor-Function-for) and [here](http://persiandate.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to store dates, you can use the `date` datatype. Similarly for times, you can use the `time` datatype.

To compute the difference, you can use the `DATEDIFF()` sql function that returns the difference between two dates: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx

I would advise against storing your data as a `string`, `int` etc. Use the datatypes as they are intended.

Comment: thanks, what about times? is there a built-in compare function for times too?

Comment: @Simon no, you can't use simple arithmetic on the new 2008+ types: `Msg 8117 ... Operand data type time is invalid for subtract operator.` Also, why would you condone [converting to varchar without specifying a length](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length.aspx)?

Comment: @AaronBertrand, sorry you are correct. Best to use the `DateDiff` function.

Answer (score 1):

For storing the data, you can use a Date type, or Time type. Once you do this the [TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx) structure can be used (in your application) to measure differences in time/dates. If you subtract one date from another then you will receive a TimeSpan object back.

```
var difference = Date1.Subtract(Date2);
```